# Overlapping on small width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have the next code and I don't know why it's not responsive..when I'm looking at the design on small width devices the content it's overlap on the image, what can I do to keep the content aside image anytime and to stop overlapping.

```
  <div class="row">

        <div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="140"
                    height="140">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
                <p>JMy name is text</p>
                <p>Hello here I am </p>
            </div>
        </div>



        </div>
```

Comment: set `img { width:100%; }`

Comment: add all class for all device width like col-md col-lg- col-sm- col-xs

Comment: @trusharwidetech Can you share the doc where you read this ? I always think that if I just set the XS it will be reproduced for the higher....

Comment: its bootstrap class for all device first you check your device width and height if its not compare to this class its will overlapping also ass img-responsive class as per @pbenard answear

Comment: In reading the doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro I see on last point, that it's not usefull to set all classes for all device width...

Answer (score 1):

Just add `img-responsive` class on the picture :

**Bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/6qzeuI7c5J

**HTML**:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <img class="rounded-circle img-responsive" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="140" height="140">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <p>JMy name is text</p>
            <p>Hello here I am </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```